Differential duality: Triangular codes vs. VT codes / Single-substitution vs. Single-deletion
Here is the introduction to my problem:
Codes correcting single-deletion. Let $q$ and $n$ be non-negative integers, and let $\mathbf{x}= \left ( x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n} \right )\in\mathbb{Z}_{q}^{n}$ be a vector. No matter which single element $x_{i}$ is deleted, it is always possible to recover $x_{i}$ using the syndrome
$a= \sum\limits_{i= 1}^{n}i\operatorname{Diff}\left ( \mathbf{x} \right )_{i}\mod qn$, where $$\operatorname{Diff}\left ( \mathbf{x} \right )= \left ( x_{1}- x_{2}, x_{2}- x_{3}, \ldots, x_{n- 1}- x_{n}, x_{n} \right )$$
(This result is part of the Differential VT codes construction: see arXiv:2311.04578.)
Codes correcting single-substitution. If we use triangular-weight for syndrome of the above construction, as $\sum\limits_{i= 1}^{n}\binom{i+ 1}{2}\operatorname{Diff}\left ( \mathbf{x} \right )_{i}= \sum\limits_{i= 1}^{n}ix_{i}$. If codeword suffers single-substitution: $x_{i}= w_{i}$, it is always possible to recover $x_{i}$ of error position $i$:
$$\frac{a- {a}'}{b- {b}'}= \frac{i\left ( x_{i}- w_{i} \right )}{x_{i}- w_{i}}= i$$
(Auxiliary checksum: $\sum\limits_{i= 1}^{n}x_{i}= b\mod q$)

Conjecture: Let $q$ and $n$ be non-negative integers, and let $\mathbf{x}= \left ( x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n} \right )\in\mathbb{Z}_{q}^{n}$ be a vector. Is it possible to always recover any single-deleted/single-subtituted $x_{i}$ using a unique codes construction of modulo $k_{q}qn$, where constant integer $k_{q}$ depends on $q$ but not $n$? (Treat DiffVT codes as a sub-code of DiffTriangular codes.)

The question arises from exploring the duality between Differential VT codes (not capable of correcting single-substitution, even with the help of auxiliary checksum), and Differential Triangular codes (not capable of correcting worst-case single-deletion. e.g., if $x_{i}= 1$ deleted, Differential Triangular codes construction does not allow us to distinguish between $\ldots\underline{1}02\ldots$ and $\ldots 02\underline{1}\ldots$). I sincerely apologize for not being able to provide more convincing evidence.
I would greatly appreciate your guidance and insights. Thanks a real lot!

what is your conjecture? do you think it's possible or not? otherwise you should relabel it as a "question" Also you have a $k_q$ factor in the last equation. What is that?

@kodlu I think it's possible. And $k_{q}$ is the constant integers that depends on $q$ not $n$.
